# angular resource not invoking my error callback function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, angular-resource

I've been at this for hours and I can't figure out why angular is not triggering my error call back when my rails back-end raises a proper error. I'm using angular 1.2.0rc1.

According to the documentation:

`non-GET "class" actions: Resource.action([parameters], postData, [success], [error])`

And I'm using it in my angular controller during a save product operation:

```
$scope.saveProduct = function(product){

  if (product.id) {
    Product.update({id: product.id},{product: product}, function(data){
      console.log('handle success')


    }, function(){
      console.log('handle error')  //THIS IS NEVER OUTPUT!

    });
  } 

}
```

Here is the resource definition:

```
angular.module('sellbriteApp.resources').factory('Product', function ($resource) {
  return $resource('/api/products/:id', { id: "@id" },
    {
      'create':  { method: 'POST' },
      'index':   { method: 'GET', isArray: true },
      'show':    { method: 'GET', isArray: false },
      'update':  { method: 'PUT' },
      'destroy': { method: 'DELETE' }
    }
  );
});
```

Here is my rails controller:

```
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @product.update(product_params)
      format.html { redirect_to [:edit, @product], notice: 'Product was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { render 'products/show.json.jbuilder', status: :accepted }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'edit' }
      format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Rails returns a 422 status when attempting to save a product with a duplicate sku, and I want to display an error msg on the front end.

I would expect that angular should execute the error handling function provided in the update call, but I can't get that far.  Instead in my console I see:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined` with an unhelpful stacktrace:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
at $http.then.value.$resolved (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js:477:32)
at wrappedCallback (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:9042:59)
at wrappedCallback (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:9042:59)
at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:9128:26
at Object.Scope.$eval (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:9953:28)
at Object.Scope.$digest (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:9809:23)
at Object.$delegate.__proto__.$digest (<anonymous>:844:31)
at Object.Scope.$apply (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:10039:24)
at Object.$delegate.__proto__.$apply (<anonymous>:855:30)
at done (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:6542:45)
```

What am I missing?

**UPDATE:**

Apparently this http interceptor is related.  If I comment this code out, the error function is called.  I had copied this snippet from some where else and modified it in order to redirect a user to the sign_up page if they hit a rails api when they are not logged in.  It must be interfering, but I'm not sure how I should fix it.

```
App.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push('securityInterceptor');
}]);

App.factory('securityInterceptor', ['$injector', '$location', '$cookieStore', function ($injector,$location,$cookieStore) {

  return function(promise) {
    var $http = $injector.get('$http');
    return promise.then(null, function(response){
      if (response.status === 401) {
        $cookieStore.remove('_angular_devise_merchant');
        toastr.warning('You are logged out');
        $location.path('/sign_in');
      } 
    });
  };


}]);
```

Comment: Interesting... if you remove the `data` param from the success fn in Product.update, does the error go away? And does the success fn run?

Comment: no, but that let me to trying other things which led me to the problem... i'm still not sure why it's related though.  I've edited my question.

Comment: Yeah that inspector is the issue!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to reject the promise in your interceptor as well, otherwise its considered as if you've 'handled' the exception.

So:

```
App.factory('securityInterceptor', ['$injector', '$location', '$cookieStore', '$q', function ($injector,$location,$cookieStore, $q) {

  return function(promise) {
    var $http = $injector.get('$http');
    return promise.then(null, function(response){
      if (response.status === 401) {
        $cookieStore.remove('_angular_devise_merchant');
        toastr.warning('You are logged out');
        $location.path('/sign_in');
      }
      return $q.reject(response);
    });
  };


}]);
```

Comment: this works now.  thanks.  I need to read up more on how $q and promises work.  Didn't really understand the documentation first time through.