# Reject deferred in $update function of an angular $resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise, angular-resource

In my angular application I update a task as follows

```
task.$update().then(function (task) {
   // success
}, function (response) {
   // failure
});
```

From the backend I get a `422` back, but the first callback is called.

My resource looks like this

```
angular.module('App')
    .factory('Task', function ($resource) {
        var resource = $resource('/admin/tasks/:id', { id: '@id' }, {
            new: {
                 method: 'GET',
                 url: '/admin/tasks/new'
            },
            update: {
                 method: 'PUT'
            },
            ...
        });

    return resource;
});
```

The question is, under which circumstances is the second callback called ? And if needed, what can I do in the `update` method such that the second callback is called?

UPDATE: The reason the success callback is called all the time is because of an error-interceptor I have

```
angular
.module('App')
    .factory('errorInterceptor', function ($location, $q, $rootScope) {
        return { 
            responseError: function (response) {
                if (response.config.url.match($location.$$host)) {
                    $rootScope.error = response;

                    return $q.reject(response);
                }

                return $q.when(response);
            } 
        };
    });
```

Apparently, if you do `return $q.when(response);` you tell angular that everything is fine, right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callbacks are specified as params to the $update() functions, like this:

```
$task.$update(function(task) {}, function(response) {})
```

See official documentation of [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) :

> The action methods on the class object or instance object can be
>   invoked with the following parameters:
>
> - HTTP GET "class" actions: Resource.action([parameters], [success], [error])
> - non-GET "class" actions: Resource.action([parameters], postData, [success], [error])
> - non-GET instance actions: instance.$action([parameters], [success], [error])

The thing is that unlike $http, $update or any resource methods don't return a promise directly. They return an empty reference.

Note that $resource uses [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) internally, hence the $http docs apply (regarding callbacks) :

> A response status code between 200 and 299 is considered a success status and will result in the success callback being called. Note that if the response is a redirect, XMLHttpRequest will transparently follow it, meaning that the error callback will not be called for such responses.

Comment: I've tried your suggesion [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3PUxx/78/) and it works. But in my application the first callback is still called. In my app its a http status code `422`, can it be that it has to do with this. Where in de docs is described how it is decided which callback is called ? Is it maybe possible that you can define your own `$update` function ?

Comment: I also found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18907117/angular-resource-not-invoking-my-error-callback-function) post, which uses an interceptor to reject the response ?! Is that really needed for a `4XX` response ?

Comment: $resource uses $http, so the docs of $http applies: 
>A response status code between 200 and 299 is considered a success status and will result in the success callback being called. Hence, anything >= 400 (not redirect) will trigger the error callback.
You only need an interceptor if you want to define a callback that is called for all your requests. The interceptor will be run before the callback define in your $resource method.

Comment: The problem of the other post you referenced was that the error interceptor wasn't rejecting the promise. Hence, the interceptor made the request successful. The callback defined at the $resource method being executed afterwards, it handled the requests as being successful.

Comment: ok. But for some reason the success callback is triggered when the backend response has a `422` status code

Comment: I think I found the issue (check my original post). So I guess I have to check the status codes there and reject

Comment: The last line of your responseError interceptor should indeed reject the promise : return $q.reject(response);

Otherwise, it means that the interceptor recovered from the Error, which is not the case.